# How to save columns into individual files using for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have a dataframe with 143 columns and  147153 rows as follows: (subset of my data)

```
    otu1    otu2         1        2        3
1: OTU_1  OTU_10  3.807355 5.403722 3.972693
2: OTU_1 OTU_100 -1.618910 0.000000 0.000000
3: OTU_1 OTU_101  0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
```

Now I need 1 and 2 columns and the consequent columns in a separate files.
the desire output will be:

File 1:

```
      otu1     otu2         1
 1:   OTU_1   OTU_10  3.807355
 2:   OTU_1  OTU_100 -1.618910
 3:   OTU_1  OTU_101  0.000000
 4:   OTU_1 OTU_1019  0.000000
 5:   OTU_1  OTU_102  0.000000
```

File 2 and so on....

```
      otu1     otu2        2
 1:   OTU_1   OTU_10 5.403722
 2:   OTU_1  OTU_100 0.000000
 3:   OTU_1  OTU_101 0.000000
 4:   OTU_1 OTU_1019 9.211077
 5:   OTU_1  OTU_102 0.000000
```

So, I tried the following code:

```
for ( i in 1:141){
  patient$i=log_trans2[,c(1:2,(i+2))]
  patient$i=patient$i[patient$i!=0]
  patient$i=merge(patient$i, OTUNames, by.x="otu2", by.y="OTUId")
  patient$i=merge(patient$i, OTUNames, by.x="otu1", by.y="OTUId")
  write.table(patient1$i, file=sprintf("patient_grahs/patient.%s.tab",i), sep = '\t',quote = FALSE)
}
```

But I am getting the error as follows:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "i", value = c(1, 2, 4)) : 
>     replacement has 3 rows, data has 0

Where I have gone wrong?

Comment: The biggest mistake you have is that you can't use a variable with `$`. Variables only work with `[`. You will also need to be careful that `patient[, 1]` is your first column but `patient[, "1"]` is your third column... using numbered column names is often a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my column names as patient_1. patient_2 etc

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do with those merge calls. What's OTUId? It's good to have your question focus on *one* task—maybe keep this one to be about writing out the files, then get to the next task as needed

Comment: I have one more file with two columns (OTUId and OTUNames). OTUid is having same content as otu1 and otu2. So i need to get OTUNames also

Comment: If there's more data that you need us to help you work with, you'll need to add it to the question

Comment: @camile. Thank you. Next tiem, I add all the data which is included in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `lapply` with `fwrite`.  Based on the data showed, it seems to be `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(log_trans2)
lapply(names(log_trans2)[3:ncol(log_trans2)], function(nm) {
     d1 <- log_trans2[, c(names(log_trans2)[1:2], nm), with = FALSE]
     d1 <- merge(d1, OTUNames, by.x="otu2", by.y="OTUId")
     d1 <- merge(d1, OTUNames, by.x="otu1", by.y="OTUId")
   fwrite(d1,  file = paste0("patients_", nm, ".txt"))})
```

The input to `fwrite` would be

```
lapply(names(log_trans2)[3:ncol(log_trans2)], function(nm) 
     log_trans2[, c(names(log_trans2)[1:2], nm), with = FALSE])
#[[1]]
#    otu1    otu2         1
#1: OTU_1  OTU_10  3.807355
#2: OTU_1 OTU_100 -1.618910
#3: OTU_1 OTU_101  0.000000

#[[2]]
#    otu1    otu2        2
#1: OTU_1  OTU_10 5.403722
#2: OTU_1 OTU_100 0.000000
#3: OTU_1 OTU_101 0.000000

#[[3]]
#    otu1    otu2        3
#1: OTU_1  OTU_10 3.972693
#2: OTU_1 OTU_100 0.000000
#3: OTU_1 OTU_101 0.000000
```

#### data

```
log_trans2 <- structure(list(otu1 = c("OTU_1", "OTU_1", "OTU_1"), otu2 = c("OTU_10", 
"OTU_100", "OTU_101"), `1` = c(3.807355, -1.61891, 0), `2` = c(5.403722, 
0, 0), `3` = c(3.972693, 0, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1:", 
"2:", "3:"))
```

Comment: I am sorry. I think there is a misplaced brackets

Comment: @MSM Sorry,  there was a typo with `,` after the `function(nm)`.  I reemoved it

Comment: I am really sorry. I am not getting any output

Comment: @MSM  I thought your dataset is `data.table` from the input showed.  Is that a data.frame or `data.table`?  If it is just a data.frame, remove the `with = FALSE`

Comment: I am Sorry.  I works perfectly. I am sorry the trouble again. If you check the question, I had two merging statements inside the for loop. how can i integrate that into lappy

Comment: @MSM I added the merge statements, but I am not clear what 'OTUNames' is.  Is it another dataset?

Comment: Yeah. It is working fine. I got the desire output. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are trying to merge your dataframes.
If your dataframe is `df` and you want to isolate and save one column at a time, you can do:

```r
for(i in 3:ncol(df))
{
   temp_df = df[,c(1,2,i)]
   write.table(temp_df, filename = paste0("patients_",i,".txt"), sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE)
}
```